# Convert DateTime Object in C# to an epoch in Mozilla

Tags: sqlite, datetime, mozilla, epoch

I need to be able to convert a `DateTime` object in C# to an epoch like the one stored in `places.sqlite`.

I've tried doing it this way, but I've realised it gives me a date in the future!

```
public static long convertDateTimeToEpoch(DateTime time)
{
    DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);

    TimeSpan ts = time - epoch;
    return (long) ts.Ticks/ 10;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Can someone please tell me the proper way of converting as I have not found any examples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is this:

```
public static long convertDateTimeToEpoch(DateTime time)
{
    DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);

    return time.Subtract(epoch).TotalMilliseconds;
}
```

Comment: @Dimitri : This is really weird. When I save the time in a text file by using DateTime.Now.toString(), it is storing a time in the future :/

Comment: @Michelle: How many hours in the future? can it be accounted by the time difference between your time zone and GMT? Can you provide a little more details on implementation?

Comment: All I am doing is this:
  TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("textfiles//lastIndexTime.txt");

            tw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
            tw.Close();

I live in Malta so its GMT+1. It is giving me a difference of around half an hour, not even an hour heh

Comment: And you're comparing time written to your system time right? What i'd do is step through the code and see what DateTime.Now returns at the moment of writing to text file.

Comment: I think I have to use DateTimeOffset